# Trying to Pass ToDataURL with over 524288 bytes Using Input Type Text

Tags: php, jquery, canvas, input, todataurl

I am trying to create an image using DataURL of a Canvas (using JavaScript). When a user hits submit, the value gets sent to an Input type text tag (e.g., `<input type='text'>`), however, apparently on Chrome, the text gets cut off when it is at length 524,288 characters.

I am sending it to an input tag because I need to obtain the value in PHP (as a $_POST['dataurltext'];), so that I can create an image and upload it to my web server.

Any ideas on how to bypass this length?

Should I use a comment box instead, maybe?

Thank you for any help, it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending `canvas` as `Blob` at `javascript`; use `fopen()` with `php://input` as parameter to read `Blob`, `stream_copy_to_stream` or `file_get_contents()` , `file_put_contents()` to process file at `php`

See [`HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob)

```
if (!HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toBlob) {
 Object.defineProperty(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype, 'toBlob', {
  value: function (callback, type, quality) {

    var binStr = atob( this.toDataURL(type, quality).split(',')[1] ),
        len = binStr.length,
        arr = new Uint8Array(len);

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++ ) {
     arr[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    callback( new Blob( [arr], {type: type || 'image/png'} ) );
  }
 });
}
```

[Beyond $_POST, $_GET and $_FILE: Working with Blob in JavaScript and PHP](http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2014/03/beyond-post-and-get-working-with-blob.html)

```
<?php

// choose a filename
$filename = "hello.json";

// the Blob will be in the input stream, so we use php://input
$input = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
$file = fopen($filename, 'wb'); 

// Note: we don't need open and stream to stream, we could've used file_get_contents and file_put_contents
stream_copy_to_stream($input, $file);
fclose($input);
fclose($file);

?>
```

Comment: In my JS code, I ended up using `var dataURL = bottleCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);` instead of `var dataURL = bottleCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");`, and that seemed to make it a lot less characters (which solved my problem). But thank you for your answer.