# JavaScript/Ajax Write to File

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I understand this question is asked a lot but the distinction here is I HAVE WEB SECURITY DISABLED.
I am creating a webapp that will never be hosted anywhere, to access the user runs `chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir [webappdirectoryhere]`
I understand how unorthodox this is but it's just for a small project.

I am using this ajax to access a local file (this wouldn't work in chrome unless you have a server running or you just disable web security like I have):

```
function loadDoc(){
    $.ajax({url: "ajax_info.txt", success: function(result){
        var variablesArray = result.split(" ");
}});
}
```

So my question is this - can I do something like this but for writing instead of reading?

EDIT:
So what I really want is a function that does the inverse of that ajax. And to write something like (variable1 + " " + variable2)
Note: I want to overwrite, not append.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136687/discussion-on-question-by-fatuglyproud-javascript-ajax-write-to-file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said you do not plan to host it anywhere you could just move your code into a Packaged app. From there you can use the [chrome.fileSystem](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) api.

Use [chooseEntry()](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-chooseEntry) to ask the user which directory they want the app to be able to read/write to. In the callback check that the returned entry is valid, and then store it for later use.

```
var userDir = null;
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'openDirectory'}, function(theEntry) {
   //do sanity check(s) and store it
   if(!theEntry.isDirectory) {
      //report error
      return;
   }
   userDir = theEntry;
});
```

Once you have a directory entry reference than you can use [getFile()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemDirectoryEntry/getFile) to get a reference to a file, creating it if it doesn't already exist, same goes for creating subdirectories just substitute `getFile` with `getDirectory`. Then use [createWriter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileEntry/createWriter) get a FileWriter instance to write to that file.

```
function saveData(filename,data){
   if(!userDir) {
      //report error
      return;
   }

   userDir.getFile(filename, {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
      if(!fileEntry || !fileEntry.isFile){
         //report error
         return;
      }

      fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
         fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
            //report success
         };
         fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
            //report error: e.toString()
         };

         //Create a Blob from the data and write it.
         var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/plain'});
         fileWriter.write(blob);
      });
   });
}

//at some point after user has selected directory
saveData("log.txt","Some data");
```

Check the various documentations for error reporting and other necessities.

If you want to only ask the user once for the directory use [retainEntry()](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-retainEntry) to save an id of the directory entry. And use [restoreEntry()](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-restoreEntry) to get the reference back of the directory. From there its just a matter of doing the steps in the saveData function. Check the documentation for other processes like reading the file.

Comment: I'd like to avoid going down this path if possible. Surely if everything is local and there are no security restrictions I could open and write to a file like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116513/javascript-new-file-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1 ?

Comment: @FatUglyProud You can install `php` and use built-in server. Else, no; use `<a>` element with `download` attribute approach, or chrome app. Note also, `--disable-web-security` flag is not necessary, you can use `--allow-file-access-from-files`, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/160245/how-do-i-make-the-google-chrome-flag-allow-file-access-from-files-permanent/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634049/how-to-print-all-the-txt-files-inside-a-folder-using-java-script/

Comment: @guest271314 my problem with `download` is the file can't be redirected to anywhere but your downloads folder, right? I also don't like the way it won't overwrite a file that already exists? Is there anyway around those issues. Also I need `--disable-web-security` for some other stuff I'm doing ;)

Comment: @FatUglyProud You can adjust `Settings`, set `Download location` to appropriate directory, check `Ask where to save each file before downloading`. Adjust file name at `Save File` dialog. If not for these settings, click or other user action could download any file to user filesysystem, potentially without user being aware of download occurring.

Comment: @guest271314 sounds perfect but I'm lost. Are you talking about Chrome's settings? As in from the menu?

Comment: @FatUglyProud Yes, you can also navigate to `chrome://settings`