# How do I read a JSON file using HTML?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var thing = [];
        var bar = $.getJSON('C:\Users\cccompro\foo.json', function(obj) {
            for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
               thing.push(obj[i]);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't work. "foo.json" contains an array of objects.

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything with `thing`. How do you know it's not working?

Comment: what do you see when you console.log(obj)

Comment: You can't read/write local files with your browser like that. You need to serve `foo.json` from a webserver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get javascript to read from a .json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711002/how-can-i-get-javascript-to-read-from-a-json-file)

Comment: At which browser are you trying? Chrome or Chromium?

Comment: @RPGillespie _"You can't read/write local files with your browser like that."_ 
 That is not entirely accurate. Yes it is possible to request files from local filesystem. And technically, it is possible to write to local filesystem using browser technologies.

Comment: As a note: `html` is a markup language, in the html5 standard a js API is defined, but reading is done using js and not html.

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, but clearly OP is a beginner and isn't understanding basic web technologies. Instead of pointing him to the technically-correct solution to X problem, I saw this as a potential XY problem and brought his attention to the fact that generally speaking you need a webserver to accomplish the common task of fetching a file.

Comment: @RPGillespie OP is trying to try processes and develop locally. See [--allow-file-access-for-files](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#allow-file-access-from-files) _"By default, file:// URIs cannot read other file:// URIs. This is an override for developers who need the old behavior for testing."_ A web server is not needed to develop locally; a browser can be used as a server; files can be requested from local filesystem. OP may simply not be aware of the procedures necessary to develop locally at certain browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read files directly from the users hard drive without the browsers permission. This would be a huge security issue if you could even though there are ways to allow this (checkout guests answer).

You could however try to make the user select the file and then read it with Javascript.
This is called the HTML 5 file API.

However, this doesn't work for any browser and you probably have to use a server anyway in this case.

For more information on this checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505333/get-the-data-of-uploaded-file-in-javascript) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript) post.

Comment: _"You cannot read files directly from the users harddrive"_ It does not appear that OP is trying to read files from another users hard drive, but from their own hard drive, which is possible

Comment: @guest271314 As far as I know there isn't a unique nor clean way that works on all browsers. I think using the HTML 5 file API is the best approach. If you know another way I would like to hear it :)

Comment: Agree that using File API is most universal approach for OP's specific requirements. OP appears to be using Chrome or Chromium, or they would not be receiving error (which they did not describe) at Firefox. See post below for several options at chrome, chromium. It is also possible to load a file at a `document` using `<link>` element

Comment: Write/Read/Write using File API [Edit, save, self-modifying HTML document; format generated HTML, JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563157/edit-save-self-modifying-html-document-format-generated-html-javascript?)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying the code at Question at Chrome or Chromium browsers, launch the browser instance with `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag set. Note that open instances of Chrome or Chromium should be closed when you launch the browser or the instance will be launched with the open browser instances' configuration folder, instead of with the flag set. You can launch Chrome or Chromium with an existing instance open and honoring the flag by using `--user-data-dir` flag with value set a different directory than open instance of Chrome or Chromium.

Technically, it is also possible to write to user file system without using an extension with `window.webkitRequestFileSystem`. Though using `chrome.fileSystem` within an extension provides an API designed to achieve the read/write.

See

- [Jquery load() only working in firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996001/jquery-load-only-working-in-firefox/32996188?s=1|2.0204#32996188)
- [Read local XML with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279589/read-local-xml-with-js/41401418?s=11|0.6909#41401418)
- [How to Write in file (user directory) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098129/how-to-write-in-file-user-directory-using-javascript/36098618?s=12|0.6489#36098618)
- [How to use webkitRequestFileSystem at file: protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502091/how-to-use-webkitrequestfilesystem-at-file-protocol?s=9|0.0981)
- [JavaScript/Ajax Write to File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460493/javascript-ajax-write-to-file/42462255#42462255)

Using `<input type="file">` element

- [How to print all the txt files inside a folder using java script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634049/how-to-print-all-the-txt-files-inside-a-folder-using-java-script/37634328?s=2|2.2633#37634328)