# Download an image to my server form data URL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am developing a site as a student project, in which you're supposed to login > take a picture with your camera > display all the pictures ever taken > like and comments picture.

I already have that piece of Javascript which draw an image on a canvas from the camera stream. Then it sets a new  element and set its 'src' attr to canvas.toDataURL(img/png); to display a preview for the pic just taken.

Now what I want, and can't find a solution for, is saving this new created picture to my server on a /img/photo1.png directory OR stock a link on the database that I can output later.

Thanks for helping.

(BTW, I'm not allowed to use any library (no JQuery please !!))

Comment: You'll have to POST a form to your server, or do it with XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Google "php file upload"

Comment: add the ```canvas.toDataURL(img/png);``` to an input text box in a form, and submit that form. then write a PHP code to for upload photo like usual.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491759/trying-to-pass-todataurl-with-over-524288-bytes-using-input-type-text/

Comment: thanks for all you answers, I still have issues tho... the problem is, the picture I'm trying to upload is not a file uploaded by the user but a javascript object...

Comment: Ok I found my answer, the thing I didn't understand is that you can (almost) directly use file_put_contents (php) on the string canvas.toDataURL(img/png) returns !

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my answer, the thing I didn't understand is that you can (almost) directly use file_put_contents (php) on the string canvas.toDataURL(img/png) returns !