# How to decode and upload GIF via AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm currently using Gifshot.js to create user avatars on my site. I want to be able to store the GIF files server side, but am unable to get it to work. The question is how do I properly decode a base64 encoded GIF file, to store via PHP? Also, is there a way to upload the files as incremented numbers, instead of a static name? Here is what I currently have for code:

**Javascript:**

```
$("#savegif").click(function(){      
    gifshot.createGIF({
        interval: 0.1,
        numFrames: 25,
    }, function (obj) {
        if (!obj.error) {

            var image = obj.image,
            animatedImage = document.getElementById('animatedgif');
            animatedImage.src = image;

            var data = animatedImage.src;
            $.ajax({ 
                url: "gifsave.php",
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "text",
                data: { data }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$file = $_POST['data'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/gif;base64,', '', $file);
file_put_contents('images/image.gif', base64_decode($img));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `POST` a `Blob` representation of file object to server and use `php://input` and `fopen()` to get the file contents at `php`, see [Trying to Pass ToDataURL with over 524288 bytes Using Input Type Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491759/trying-to-pass-todataurl-with-over-524288-bytes-using-input-type-text/).

```
fetch("gifsave.php", {method:"POST", body:blob})
.then(response => response.ok)
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

You can stream the file as chunks to server by converting a `Blob` to an `ArrayBuffer`, creating a `TypedArray`, for example, a `Uint8Array`, with `ArrayBuffer` as parameter, and streaming the file to server using `WebSocket`.