# Not able to save/download browser blob data object

Tags: javascript, perl, browser, html5-video, bloburls

I have a web page where user uploads a video file using html's "input type = file" tag, I am catching that uploaded video file in JavaScript function variable where it is coming as blob URL. "blob:https://www.myownsite.com:8080/2e8cfd32-abf2-4db3-b396-91f76cc3b40c". I am not able to save this blob URL in my system.

HTML code:

```
<input type="file" name="video_file_name" accept="video/*">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Video" id="customVideoSubmit">
<button onClick="postVideo();" id="customVideoSubmit" aria- hidden="true">Upload Video</button>
```

JavaScript code:

```
    function postVideo(){
    var blobURL = document.querySelector('video').src;
}
```

variable blobURL contains following blob URL, which plays video properly if I put this on a separate tab of that browser.

```
blob:https://www.myownsite.com:8080/2e8cfd32-abf2-4db3-b396-91f76cc3b40c
```

How can I save this blob video file in my system. I have tried number of JavaScript methods and also back end methods in my Perl code like

```
decode_base64($cgi->{blobURL}) ;
```

Nothing worked though. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Where is `Blob URL` created? Is requirement to save file to local filesystem or server?

Comment: On the server. the blobURL has server path, however it is only in the browser memory. blobURL is being created by the browser. It is a browser object.

Comment: `POST` the `data URI`, `Blob` or `File` representation of file to server, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557180/how-to-decode-and-upload-gif-via-ajax-and-php/46557251#46557251

Comment: I am able to POST the blobURL to the server. Perl CGI variable $cgi->{'blobURL'} in my back end Perl script has full URL path of blobURL. So, I have blobURL at server backend just don't know how to save it.

Comment: Convert `Blob URL` to `Blob`. It is not possible to process a `Blob URL` at server.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a `Blob URL` to a `Blob` to `POST` to server you can use `fetch()` and `Response.blob()`

```js
const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([123]));
fetch(blobURL)
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(blob => {
  // do stuff with `blob`: `Blob`
  console.log(blob);
});
```

Comment: Have you read linked Question at previously posted comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638009/not-able-to-save-download-browser-blob-data-object/46639149?noredirect=1#comment80225489_46638009?